# Category pagination first link works, remaining don't

Tags: permalinks, pages, pagination

In our website, for one of our categories ([`rentals -> sconces`](http://lighthousevancouver.com/products-page/sconce/)), page one works fine, but the remaining 3 don't.

I've read in a couple places to just set the permalink back to default, but I wanted to confirm before I start trying to fix it.

Comment: The shortcode right? sorry still kinda learning as i go lol

Comment: I personally havent done anything at all. I actually kind of inherited this because the last guy that was doing it made a complete mess of the whole site so ive been trying to learn as much as i can in hopes of fixing it all

Comment: ok i found, but its huge. too long to post it says

Comment: Having looked again, your issue is not pagination, which appears to be fine. Your page 3 is actually broken. If you could turn on error messages that would help identify the issue. Do you have access to the files over FTP? You need to turn on WP_DEBUG, as described [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress).